# Trying to authenticate using oauth2 azure ad with users in SQL database

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-active-directory, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate users on a Nodejs app using express. I am using the 'passport-azure-ad-oauth2' package.

My list of users are stored in a sql database, not mongodb... so I am unsure of using mongoose etc.

I am at the stage where when accessing localhost:3000, it redirects to the login and only users in the Active Directory can pass through this step.

After following the login process, I am able to display in the console the email of the user who just signed in (`userInfo.upn`), but then it just takes me to the `/login` route specified for failureRedirect.

My problem is that I don't understand how the `done()` function works and how to implement the code which searches the list of users in the database and matches them up against userInfo.upn. I feel this is similar to the .findOrCreate method - but I can't understand any documentation on this either.

I do know how to connect to my database and write some code to verify if userInfo.upn matches an email in the database, but I am not sure of how to use the `done()` function to then redirect to the relevant routes.

Basically I just want to simply implement:

`Loop through list of users in SQL DB`

then

```
if(there is a match between userInfo.upn and an email in the database){//go to landing page} else {//go to the 'you don't have permission' page}
```

My understanding is that the authentication (keeping out users) is already done. I think I could just do a hacky thing and keep the code as is then set the `/login` route to be the landing page and I guess that would work but I know this isn't how it is supposed to be done - I really want to understand the proper way to do it and how it works.

I have tried searching through passport documentation but I am still stuck.

If someone could help me with the correct code with some explanations, it would be much appreciated.

My code is below

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")
const passport = require("passport");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const jwt = require("jwt-simple");


const app = express();

const AzureAdOAuth2Strategy = require('passport-azure-ad-oauth2').Strategy;



app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));



passport.use(new AzureAdOAuth2Strategy({
    clientID: 'registeredClientID',
    clientSecret: 'registeredClientSecret',
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/.auth/login/aad/callback',
   
  },
  function (accessToken, refresh_token, params, profile, done) {
    var waadProfile = profile || jwt.decode(params.id_token, '_~KrAjv.8CfRFA7Rp-8FVf-1G4owo_SI5_', true);
    console.log(params.id_token);
    console.log(waadProfile);
    // console.log(jwt.decode(params.id_token, '_~KrAjv.8CfRFA7Rp-8FVf-1G4owo_SI5_', true));
    var userInfo = jwt.decode(params.id_token, '_~KrAjv.8CfRFA7Rp-8FVf-1G4owo_SI5_', true);
    console.log(userInfo.upn);

    done();
   
    //*******this is where i'm confused don't know what code to implement//////

    // User.findOrCreate({ id: waadProfile.upn }, function (err, user) {
    //   done(err, user);
    // });
  }));


  app.get("/",passport.authenticate('azure_ad_oauth2'));

  app.get('/.auth/login/aad/callback', 
  passport.authenticate('azure_ad_oauth2', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    console.log(res);
    res.render('index');
  });

  



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log("Server started on Port 3000");
  });
```

Comment: Hi @b.b.89, Are you storing Azure AD login credentials i.e., username and password in Database??

Comment: Hi there, thanks for reply. I am not trying to store their credentials - only their email address because I just want to check if they are a permitted user of the web app (not all users in the AAD will be actually allowed to use the app)